# Storing Highscore in Unity C# code not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, game-engine

So, I've been trying to store highscore of my player but no matter how much I try the return is 0.

Here's the score setting

```
  highScore = playerScoref();
           if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score") < highScore) {
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Score", highScore);
            }
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
       }
```

and this is where I get back the code

```
       Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
       highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score");
       Debug.Log(highScore);
```

Comment: what is `playerScoref()` ?

Comment: Also when is the score setting code being called (are you sure it is being called)?

Comment: the code should work correctly which means that either `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat()` is never reached or that `highScore` value is always 0.

Comment: Maybe post the entire code instead? There is not enough information with the current codes that is given.

Comment: maybe you can post the the code playerScoref() function and PlayerPrefs class ?

Comment: Is `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Score")` set? you should add a check that it is `if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Score")){//Now get it}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    private int ingameScore;
    private int highScore;
    private bool gameOver;
    private bool callOnce;

    void Start() {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore")) {
            highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
        }
        else {
            //creating the key for highscore
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", 0);
            highScore = 0;
        }
    }

    void Update() {

        //if player lost the game set gameover boolean to true
        //and use callOnce boolean to call these block only once and only for one frame
        //to avoid extra cpu usage
        if (gameOver && !callOnce) {

            //and check if player collected higher score then highscore is and assign it 
            //to playerpref's highscore key 
            if(ingameScore > highScore) {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", ingameScore);
            }

            callOnce = true;
        }
    }
}
```